# Referencing asp.net mvc app from another asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, msbuild

I have 2 asp.net mvc 5 applications in one solution. One project have reference to second for having access to routes of second app. When I publish first application to web server, all views from second application gets copied to first. How can I avoid this?

```
Solution
-Project1 (have reference to Project2)
--Views
---Folder1
----View1.cshtml
---Folder2
----View2.cshtml
-Project2
--Views
---Folder3
----View3.cshtml
```

After deploy:

```
Solution
-Project1 (have reference to Project2)
--Views
---Folder1
----View1.cshtml
---Folder2
----View2.cshtml
---Folder3
----View3.cshtml
-Project2
--Views
---Folder3
----View3.cshtml
```

Comment: You don't need a reference to the second solution. Just use the relative path to work out how to call things from the first solution.

Comment: Just extract the functionality you need into a separate library (.dll), then reference it from both Project1 and Project2.

Comment: Routing code has references to controller classes (I am using generic helpers with lambdas for strong-typed routing), so I can't just extract them to separate library without reference to web project.